# What does version mismatch mean

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [version mismatch error](https://superuser.com/questions/502385/version-mismatch-error)

I am getting the following error `the programme version does not match the CD/DVD version`. I no that this means that the CD/DVD that I have inserted does not match the version of the program that is installed. But I have tried to install the new version but when I do I still get this error, any ideas why?

Comment: At a minimum you will have to uninstall the previous version.

Comment: I have tried to uninstall the previous version, but when I tried to do this on Windows 7 it did not appear in the add/remove program list in the control panel so I tried removing it where ever I could find this but I am still getting the same error... I was then thinking this was not fully removed so I have tried using software to search for partially deleted software but this did not find any partly deleted programs so this did not work

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Niall, Looking at your comments above and the fact that you are using Windows. It leads me to believe that you uninstalled a particular program and you needed to restart but you didn't. When you need to restart and don't other programs will still believe that the program is installed. So after uninstalling the original program, restart, then attempt to install the new version.

Comment: by 'restart' do you mean restarting the computer? If so I have already tried this but it still gives the same error

Comment: yes indeed I did mean restarting the computer. If the program truly doesn't have any files anywhere on your computer then this message would not come up (assuming the new version is not faulty). That means somewhere on your computer in the registry or in a configuration file-something is telling that cd that the program is on the computer. Might I ask what the CD/DVD is for? maybe its program specific.

Comment: That must be what is happening because I do not think it is installed on the computer, something must be telling the CD/DVD that it is already installed but I am not familiar with this so I do not know what to remove/clean/edit to fix this....... I am trying to install a newer version of a program called Autodata, I have installed it on my home computer and it worked fine(no pervious version on my computer) so the version is not faulty, but when I tried to install this on my laptop I get this error message